# Turning function that has a combination of publishers/sinks into an async function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have the following function `loadData` and I want to use it within `refreshable` of a SwiftUI list. For this I need to make it an `async` function:

```
func loadData() {
  // Publishers
  let followersPublisher = modelLoader.loadAllFollowers(withId: id)
  let followingPublisher = modelLoader.loadAllFollowing(withId: id)
  let friendshipsPublisher = Publishers.Zip(followersPublisher, followingPublisher)
    .share()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

  // Sinks
  getFollowers(from: followersPublisher)
  getFollowerChange(
    from: followersPublisher,
    cachedFollowers: followers
  )
  getFollowing(from: followingPublisher)
  getNotFollowingUserBack(from: friendshipsPublisher)
  getUserNotFollowing(from: friendshipsPublisher)

  followersPublisher
    .connect()
    .store(in: &cancellables)
  followingPublisher
    .connect()
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

Within this function, all the separate functions use `Publisher` sinks. For example:

```
private func getFollowing(from publisher: Publishers.MakeConnectable<AnyPublisher<Set<User>, Never>>) {
  publisher
    .sink(
      receiveCompletion: { _ in },
      receiveValue: { [weak self] following in
        self?.following = following
      }
    )
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

How can I turn it into an `async` function so I can use `await` with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Combine Publisher has a `values` property that is an async sequence:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/values-1dm9r

Thus any pipeline that starts with a Publisher can be replaced by `async/await` code, capturing the `values` using an `async` for loop. So if you want to, you could keep on using your `followersPublisher` and your `followingPublisher` and just subscribe to them using `async/await` instead of Combine.

On the other hand, depending what those publishers do, you might want to follow this chain further back and get rid of those publishers and replace them by `async` methods that you can call from an `async/await` context.